# How to systematically collect advanced vocabulary?

Tags: vocabulary

I am currently adding upper-intermediate and advanced vocabulary flashcards in [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net), and I'm using a lot of sources for that, like

- books ("English Vocabulary in Use Upper-Intermediate/Advanced", anthologies in English, but with translated vocabulary as footnotes, picture dictionaries, etc.)
- websites (vocabulary.com)
- apps (IELTS and GRE apps)
- Wikipedia, newspaper articles etc. (I simply write everything down I
  don't know and add it)

However, since I've started doing that I've always had the wish to do it more systematically and faster.
I'm looking for a collection of advanced vocabulary that is neither too trivial, nor too specialized. It shouldn't contain words like "door", "flower" or "car", but it doesn't have to contain words like "homotropic", "Epicurean" or "epenthesis" either. A collection that contains words like "wisdom tooth", "exuberance" or "cantakerous"; words that you normally don't learn at school when you learn English as a second language, but that a native speaker of English usually knows. Or to put it differently, a collection of non-trivial everyday vocabulary.

There is only one collection I've found yet that vaguely addresses my needs, Advanced English 2014. It contains about 45,000 words, phrases etc. from beginner to advanced. However, I'd have to buy Supermemo together with it, and since it is for Windows only I'd always have to switch my OS (Usually, I use Linux). Is there something else around that concentrates on intermediate and advanced vocabulary, but doesn't stop at 1,000 or so words?

(I've seen "Resources for learning English" on Meta, but there is nothing which really addresses this specific question.)

Comment: If you want to improve your vocabulary, it's best to read books. Read Dickens, there's a lot of vocabulary. Or any good author like: John Fowles. If you don't see words in context, you'll never remember them. Reading is best. BOOKS and not websites or web content. That way you get to expand your mind and your vocabulary. Good magazines are OK too, like The New Yorker or the Atlantic Monthly. If you don't read words in a context that makes sense, and just collect loose words, it's a worthless exercise, in my opinion.

Comment: Actually, I did that "no context" mistake at the beginning, so I now always add three example sentences for each meaning in Anki, if possible (sometimes I have words that are so obscure that it is hard to find any meaningful example sentences, but thankfully this is rare). I have now always also an English definition.

Comment: I doubt many people know what an Anki deck is. I sure don't.

Comment: I've edited my post.

Comment: Just to add something to your comment: I agree that good books and magazines are great for expanding vocabulary. It is just that I had to get 43 years old to see the word "coat hanger" for the first time, and only by chance (it was in a statement about words you normally don't read about). I read a lot of English every day, but such words somehow never end up in the books or articles I read. That's why I wanted to speed up things a bit.

Comment: Well, coat hanger is the kind of word you get from living in a place. So.....:) Perhaps you should spend more time with comedians on utube, they use a lot of everyday words you might not read in articles. And I don't just mean the dirty ones.

Comment: I think you have a point here with the "Real Life" Youtube; I guess I'll try that...

Comment: Try the TV show; Big Bang Theory, excellent vocabulary, excellent humor and a top quality comedy team. If you can get it where you are.

Comment: Thanks. I'll ask the warden of our labor camp if we're allowed to watch it.

Comment: Warden of your labor camp???

Comment: I've strayed into fiction. It's fact-based that Big Bang Theory is the most popular series here, though. It seems I've somewhat fallen behind regarding following what's going on.